# Concatenating values in mysql where multiple rows in one table relate to one row in another table

Tags: mysql, grouping, concatenation

I have two mysql tables, one listing article names, the other listing the authors associated with each article, as follows:

```
   article_id     title
 =======================
        1         art1
        2         art2
        3         blob


  article_id      name      surname
 =====================================
       1           jack       smith
       1           jill       jones
       1           rob        edgar
       2           billy      bryce
       3           dick       bonsor
       3           jeff       kucick
```

I am trying to create a query that will return the following:

```
 article_id     title                 author
 =========================================================
      1          art1     jack smith, jill jones, rob edgar 
      2          art2                billy bryce
      3          blob          dick bonsor, jeff kucick
```

I have been looking at group_concat and concat_ws, but I have been unsuccessful in my attempts to return the above result. If any of you have any thoughts on this, I would be most grateful!

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select
  a.article_id,
  a.title,
  group_concat(concat(p.name, ' ', p.surname)) as author
from
  article a
  inner join author p on p.article_id = a.article_id
group by
  a.article_id, 
  a.title
```

or, if you want to use concat_ws:

```
select
  a.article_id,
  a.title,
  group_concat(concat_ws(' ', p.name, p.surname)) as author
from
  article a
  inner join author p on p.article_id = a.article_id
group by
  a.article_id, 
  a.title
```

Comment: hi, wow, quick response! thanks! i have no idea who downvoted you... let me try out your answer though and see what happens... thanks so much!

Comment: That is unbelievably awesome, thanks so much! I knew there would be a way to do it but it was slightly beyond my current mysql abilities!

Comment: Well, you found the right functions already. :) Glad I could help.

Comment: I do have one further question now that i think about it... how would i sort the order of the authors in this query. For example if i wanted them to appear arranged alphabetically by surname, or ordered by another column in the authors table that's not included in the current query...a 'position' column, for example?

Comment: Ignore that, I've figured it out... very simple. Thanks again.